android ndk loading library on runtime from local path
I have library.so, I created wrapper in C and the issue is that on Runtime when I load the wrapper, it is trying to find the library on local path.
Application.mk
APP_ABI := arm64-v8a x86_64

Android.mk
# v2 - use the prebuilt .so library

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

#enable our C sources to call prebuilt .so library
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := RokuDriver-prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../jniLibs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libRokuDriver.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

#build our own C sources
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := TestDriver
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := TestDriver.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := RokuDriver-prebuilt
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

Java
public class RokuDriver {
    static {
        try {
            System.loadLibrary("TestDriver");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.error(e);
        }
    }

    public native String stringFromJNI();

    public void call() {
        Log.debug("--------------------------------------------------------------" + stringFromJNI());
    }
}

gradle
android {
    namespace 'secret'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "secret"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }

        ndk {
            abiFilters "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    ndkVersion '26.1.10909125'
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
        }
    }
}

TestDriver.c (still missing anything related to RokuDriver as I am unable to even load it.)
#include <jni.h>        // JNI header provided by JDK
#include <stdio.h>      // C Standard IO Header
#include "TestDriver.h"   // Generated

JNIEXPORT jstring Java_secret_jni_RokuDriver_stringFromJNI(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj) {
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from JNI !  Compiled with ABI.");
}

TestDriver.h
#include <jni.h>

#ifndef _Included_secret_jni_RokuDriver
#define _Included_secret_jni_RokuDriver
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

JNIEXPORT jstring Java_secret_jni_RokuDriver_stringFromJNI(JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif

error
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "C:\projects\Android\app\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\1eh3n2g7/obj/local/arm64-v8a/libRokuDriver.so" not found                                                                           
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:977)                                                  
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1530)                                           
at secret.jni.RokuDriver.<clinit>(RokuDriver.java:18)                   
at secret.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:104)

The file is present at C:\projects\Android\app\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\1eh3n2g7/obj/local/arm64-v8a/libRokuDriver.so and the apk also has the libRokuDriver.so at /libs/arm64-v8a/libRokuDriver.so
but why is it loading the library at runtime from local path instead of /libs/arm64-v8a/libRokuDriver.so
I am following the official Android guide here and dozens of articles and it is mindblowing that official Android guides do not work a single time.
If I omitt the prebuilt library and only compile TestDriver.c it works and I see in the Logcat the output.

This is probably the result of your prebuilt libraries having been built with a really old (or misconfigured) NDK. You'll have to find newer versions of those libraries, or build them yourself if possible.

Thank you, but I am missing to see any connection between what is inside the library or how it was built with the fact that is called from my local path during runtime.

See e.g. https://github.com/android/ndk/issues/177
